# How to show one element and hide all others with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, display, ng-show

When a person clicks on a button, with ng-click directive, I call a function openAbout(), I want one div to be shown and all others to be hidden. It works with this code, but is there any what to make only two statements, instead of five? I want for example, first to be shown and all others hidden. Thanks

```
<md-button id="about" ng-click="openAbout()">
     About Us
</md-button>


$scope.openAbout=function() {
    document.getElementById("first").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("third").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("fifth").style.display = "none";      
};
```

Comment: Yes, I am working with Angular

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
$scope.openAbout=function(){
  $(".divClass").hide(); // give all divs the same class
  $("#first").show();
};
```

unless you want to use ngShow/ngHide: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide

Comment: It doesn't work with that, I have tried.

Comment: What does "doesn't work with that" mean? Errors in console?

Comment: No, it doesn't hide the elements, all of them are on the page still.

Comment: You have not given us enough code to see why

Comment: I think that's because you didn't add the class `divClass` to the divs you want to hide.

Comment: Or the openAbout does not trigger?

Comment: I've added more code now. Yeah, it doesn't do anything

Comment: Show some more HTML?